# How To Get The Pixel Count Of A Segmented Area in an Image I used Vgg16 for Segmentation

Tags: python, tensorflow, opencv, deep-learning, pytorch

I am new to deep learning but have succeeded in semantic segmentation of the image I am trying to get the pixel count of each class in the label. As an example in the image I want to get the pixel count of the carpet, or the chandelier or the light stand. How do I go about? Thanks any suggestions[image: segmented image] will help.

Comment: please give a lot more detail. present the steps from receiving the result of inference to a fully colored segmentation.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I will do and tag you. Also will follow you on github. Thanks for responding. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:** In what format the regions are returned? Do you have only the final image or the regions are given as contours? If you have them as contours (list of coordinates), you can apply findContourArea directly on that structure.

1. If you can receive/sample the regions one by one in an image (but do not have the contour), you can sequentially paint each of the colors/classes in a clear image, either convert it to grayscale or directly paint it in grayscale or binary, or binarize with threshold; then numberPixels = len(cv2.findNonZero(bwImage)). cv2.findContour and cv2.contourArea should do the same.
2. Instead of rendering each class in a separate image, if your program receives only the final segmentation and not per-class contours, you can filter/mask the regions by color ranges on that image. I built that and it seemed to do the job, 14861 pixels for the pink carpet:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# rgb 229, 0, 178 # the purple carpet in RGB (sampled with IrfanView)
# b,g,r = 178, 0, 229 # cv2 uses BGR
class_color = [178, 0, 229]
multiclassImage = cv2.imread("segmented.png")
cv2.imshow("MULTI", multiclassImage)
filteredImage = multiclassImage.copy()
low = np.array(class_color);

mask = cv2.inRange(filteredImage, low, low)
filteredImage[mask == 0] = [0, 0, 0]
filteredImage[mask != 0] = [255,255,255]
cv2.imshow("FILTER", filteredImage)
# numberPixelsFancier = len(cv2.findNonZero(filteredImage[...,0]))
# That also works and returns 14861 - without conversion, taking one color channel
bwImage = cv2.cvtColor(filteredImage, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)  
cv2.imshow("BW", bwImage)
numberPixels = len(cv2.findNonZero(bwImage))
print(numberPixels)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

3. If you don't have the values of the colors given or/and can't control them, you can use `numpy.unique()`: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html and it will return the unique colors, then they could be applied in the algorithm above.
4. **Edit 2:** BTW, another way to compute or verify such counts is by calculating histograms. That's with IrfanView on the black-white image:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. I really appreciate the guide and will try it our. I will get back when I am done with the steps you provided. Thanks a again and do have a great day.