# Python, crop an image to extract a single side of it

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing

I have an image and the vertexs of each sides of it, meaning that, if we see each side as a segment (A,B) i have both the A and B point coordinates.

Now i would like to crop the image so that i have only one segment of the image (which is the side), for example [That's just one side of the original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tVHGE.png)

For now i tried to do it in opencv with binary masking creating a line (fromt he vertexes i have) and using it to crop the image so that i have the pixels corresponding to that side. The problem with this approach is that the resulting image is of the same size of the orginal one but everything that is cropped is now a [0,0,0,0] (rgba) pixel

Instead, what i want is the following: if for example the side i want to extract is 20px long, the resulting image should be of shape (1,20,4) 1 height, 20 width and 4 channels (rgba)

I tried to do it with slicing but I don't know how to account to the fact that the sides can also be oblique lines.

Example image: [Example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d0ery.png)
Corresponding vertexes: [[[107, 32], [95, 30]], [[95, 30], [26, 103]], [[26, 103], [28, 119]], [[28, 119], [103, 109]], [[103, 109], [122, 64]], [[122, 64], [107, 32]]]
Each of these vertex is needed so i can extract, for every 2 vertex, a line from the image. In the previuos example i have 12 vertexes, so it will be 6 lines that i have to extract

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need use numpy obligatorily, you can use Image from PIL

```
from PIL import Image

img1 = Image.open(r"image_name.png")

img1 = img1.crop((cord_x, cord_y, width, height))

img1.save("name_saved.png")
```

**UPDATE:**
The another code, help for rectangle shapes, here is a more generic code for any array of polygon cords

```
import numpy
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

im = Image.open("image_name").convert("RGBA") #only convert if is necesary
image_array = numpy.asarray(im)

#Create mask
polygon = [(107, 32), (95, 30), (26, 103), (28, 119), (103, 109), (122, 64)] #this cords is from your example
mi = Image.new('L', (image_array.shape[1], image_array.shape[0]), 0)
ImageDraw.Draw(mi).polygon(polygon, outline=1, fill=1)
mask = numpy.array(mi)

new_image_array = numpy.empty(image_array.shape,dtype='uint8')
new_image_array[:,:,:3] = image_array[:,:,:3]
new_image_array[:,:,3] = mask*255

#Convert numpy array to image
image_output = Image.fromarray(new_image_array, "RGBA")
image_output.save("file_output_name")
```

Comment: Can you elaborate more on cord_x, cord_y? Because for each side i have two points (x1,y1) (x2,y2) and not onw

Comment: cord_x and cord_y are the coordinates from the top-left corner, from there you define the width and height that you need.

Comment: This would crop a rectangular region, it seems Marco wants to extract a shape defined by a polygon. You can do such a rectangular crop with slices, Marco mentioned that he tried with slices already: https://learnopencv.com/cropping-an-image-using-opencv/

 img = cv2.imread('test.jpg')
 print(img.shape) # Print image shape
 cv2.imshow("original", img); 
 cropped_image = img[80:280, 150:330]

Comment: Okay this kinda work but not with every image or border, for example:
If i use the first two points or the 2nd and 3rd to extract the corresponding segment [(107,32), (95,30)] or [(95,30), (26,103)] it tells me "tile cannot extend outside image", referring to the line:
image_output.save("name.png") on the other hand i tried it with another image/border and it worked

Comment: That error is caused when you use a point out from the image, i don't know why that is hapenning, because  according to what you say, if you use [(107, 32), (95,30), (26, 103)] it's working. You must analyze the error

Comment: okay then, i think this is due to the fact the the vertexes are extracted from the image with an aproximation of it contour. So if the aproximation would have been better, i wouldn't have had problems

Comment: I guess. I was trying with many images and always worked. I don't know why you got that error

Answer (score 0):

So as far as I understand your question, it seems that you are able to crop with numpy slices and with a mask and manage the alpha channel, but you need to extract that cropped region as a bounding box of the shape?

As long as you have the coordinates which define the polygon, you can find the leftmost, rightmost, topmost and the bottom coordinates and slice that region.

See my answer for this example:

[Finding patches of certain colors with a size smaller than x. (x =number of pixels)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65376137/finding-patches-of-certain-colors-with-a-size-smaller-than-x-x-number-of-pixe/65376489#65376489)

If your coordinates = c:

```
c = [[[107, 32], [95, 30]], [[95, 30], [26, 103]], [[26, 103], [28, 119]], [[28, 119], [103, 109]], [[103, 109], [122, 64]], [[122, 64], [107, 32]]]
```

Then you find the extreme coordinates with something like that (given that the coordinates are in the format [y,x] as it seems)

```
top = tuple(c[c[:,:,].argmin()][0]
bottom = tuple(c[c[:,:,].argmax()][0]
left = tuple(c[c[:,:,].argmin()][1]
right = tuple(c[c[:,:,].argmax()][1]
```

( You can just iterate and find the max/min in a more ordinary way to verify for more complex examples, if you wish to use a simpler code.)

You know is it reasonable to add one pixel margin on each sides, so left = left - 1, right = right+1, top = top - 1, bottom = bottm + 1, but then you have to watch is the new value < 0 or > the end of the image.